# How to handle very large number of proximity alerts?

Tags: android, android-alarms, android-location

I have built a proximity alert based application on Android and it's working fine as expected and firing the alerts perfectly.

As an continuing effort, I now want to address the scalability aspect of this application. So essentially I am trying to address a scenario where each user might be subscribed to say 10 to 20 categories and each category may have 100 POI (points of interest like shopping) in a particular city. So there will be a total of 2000+ alerts that has to be registered on a user's phone at once.

This has 2 consequences:

1. Fetching 2000 alerts over the web from the repository for the subscriber might be in 10-20 MiB size and hang on the Android device while loading over a slow connection.
2. Even if all the alerts load, it will consume a lot of memory on the device.

In order to mitigate this I am looking for a strategy to scale this app appropriately. Is there a way I can find out extended information about the current location and request only loading alerts within a perimeter of a kilometer maybe? Or any other recommended strategy to deal with this requirement. A code sample in this regard will be great...

Thanks,
Biplab

Comment: understand your problem but what have you tried?

Comment: minhaz - well as of now all alerts gets pushed from the server via a web service to the app when the user logs in. Having said that I haven't tested the app under a scenario by throwing such a large number of alerts say 2000.

Answer (score 0):

Why not something simple-  query the webservice and have it return all positions subscribed to within 1 degree of latitude and longitude of the passed in location (the user's location).  Then check the location on the client every half hour or so via alarm and query for the new list based on your new location.

Comment: I agree. @OP, plus a side note: if the user just starts using your app then the DB is zero. He can create any POIs he needs and the app just synchronizes data with your server. If he's been using the web version for a while and now is going to install the Android app, show him option to synchronize the whole DB to his phone. Querying 2,000 records in SQLite in Android takes not much time, just some seconds at most. You can test with this app [RL Benchmark: SQLite](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.redlicense.benchmark.sqlite).

Comment: @ Gabe - Thanks for your reply. And I did think about the approach you've mentioned but I am yet to implement the code in action and see the timeliness and accuracy. I can't really check after half an hour, because considering the user is on the move that would mean he will travel quite a lot by that time. Rather I think I can use distance as the factor to refresh the alerts. But will deregistering alerts work properly? Won't constant registering/deregistering cause any issues?

Comment: @ Lai - Thanks for your reply. I am not really worried about fetching the DB records and the latency. But it's about the time it will take to get these 2000+ odd alert data to the phone over say a slow connection like GPRS (2G). In addition to that the other concern is then loading/registering all these 2000 alerts at once - will that have any impact on the memory and battery drainage?

Comment: Deregistering alerts shouldn't cause issues, in fact its best practices not to have them if you don't need them (they cost the OS processing time on every location upgrade).  I think time should work perfectly well as a trigger to check so long as you give enough data per request, but either time or distance will work, the same basic idea is still sound.